# How to insert new key value pair in array of objects depending on two different keys?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects as follow:

```
const data = [{
    groupId:1,
    date:"07/10/2022", 
    employeeName:"Jhon"
  }, {
    groupId:1,
    date:"07/10/2022", 
    employeeName:"Sam"
  }, {
    groupId:2,
    date:"07/10/2022", 
    employeeName:"Max"
  }, {
    groupId:1,
    date:"09/10/2022", 
    employeeName:"Sabstian"
  }, {
    groupId:2,
    date:"09/10/2022", 
    employeeName:"Karina"
  }, {
    groupId:2,
    date:"09/10/2022", 
    employeeName:"Terry"
  }]
```

I want to add new key to each object "itemNumber", that key will be calculated as follow:

1. Objects which have same date will get "itemNumber" as 1, 2, 3..., For example, in given
   data if 'groupId' is '1' and 'date' is '07/10/2022' for those objects itemNumber will be
   "1" and "2". Now if I go to the next object which has 'groupId' as '2' and 'date' is
   '07/10/2022' then it should get itemNumber "3"
2. When 'groupId' changes I need to check the previous groupId's maximum itemNumber value
   depending on that current groupId's object will get the itemNumber. Maximum
   number of objects for same date and for same groupId should be considered, before
   assigning the itemNumber. For example, for groupId "1" maximum number of objects are for date '07/10/2022' which are '2' hence items for 'groupId' = '2' will get itemNumber from '3' onwards

Expected result is as follow:

```
  const data = [{
    groupId:1,
    date:"07/10/2022", 
    employeeName:"Jhon",
    itemNumber:1
  }, {
    groupId:1,
    date:"07/10/2022", 
    employeeName:"Sam",
    itemNumber:2
  }, {
    groupId:2,
    date:"07/10/2022", 
    employeeName:"Max",
    itemNumber:3
  }, {
    groupId:1,
    date:"09/10/2022", 
    employeeName:"Sabstian",
    itemNumber:1
  }, {
    groupId:2,
    date:"09/10/2022", 
    employeeName:"Karina", 
    itemNumber:3
  }, {
    groupId:2,
    date:"09/10/2022", 
    employeeName:"Terry",
    itemNumber:4
  }]
```

I used array.reduce method based on date but it only gave me itemNumber depending on date which is as follow:

```
  const expectedData = data.reduce((expectedData, item) => {
    const d = (expectedData[item.date] || []);
    d.push(item);
    expectedData[item.date] = d;
    return expectedData;
  }, {});

  let expedctedOutputArray = []

  for (var key of Object.keys(expectedData)) {
    expedctedOutputArray.push(expectedData[key].map((data, index) => ({...data, itemNumber:index + 1})))
}
let mergedOutputArray = [].concat.apply([], expedctedOutputArray);
```

Comment: why `{ grouppId:1, date:"07/10/2022", employeeName:"Sam" }` is expected as `{ grouppId:2, date:"07/10/2022", employeeName:"Sam", itemNumber:2 }` I mean why `grouppId:1` becomes 2?

Comment: @GrafiCode It was just typing mistake, I edited the code, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the working solution. I have added extra element in input data for test result.

```
const data = [{
  groupId: 1,
  date: "07/10/2022",
  employeeName: "Jhon"
}, {
  groupId: 1,
  date: "07/10/2022",
  employeeName: "Sam"
}, {
  groupId: 2,
  date: "07/10/2022",
  employeeName: "Max"
}, {
  groupId: 3,
  date: "07/10/2022",
  employeeName: "Koye"
}, {
  groupId: 1,
  date: "09/10/2022",
  employeeName: "Sabstian"
}, {
  groupId: 2,
  date: "09/10/2022",
  employeeName: "Karina"
}, {
  groupId: 2,
  date: "09/10/2022",
  employeeName: "Terry"
}]


//Find occurence of each group and date
function findOcc(arr, key1, key2) {
  let arr2 = [];
  //key1 is group & key2 is date
  arr.forEach((x) => {
    if (arr2.some((val) => {
      return val[key1] == x[key1] && val[key2] == x[key2]
    })) {
      arr2.forEach((k) => {
        if (k[key1] == x[key1] && k[key2] == x[key2]) {
          k["occurrence"]++
        }
      })

    } else {
      let a = {}
      a[key1] = x[key1]
      a[key2] = x[key2]
      a["occurrence"] = 1
      arr2.push(a);
    }
  })
  return arr2
}
const occurenceArray = findOcc(data, "groupId", "date")


//Sort the input data
data.sort(function (a, b) {
  var keyA = new Date(a.date),//a.groupId,//
  keyB = new Date(b.date);//b.groupId//
  // Compare the 2 dates
  if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
  if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
  return 0;
});

//Find the max value from each group
var result = [];
occurenceArray.forEach(function (a) {
  if (!this[a.groupId]) {
    this[a.groupId] = { groupId: a.groupId, occurrence: 0 };
    result.push(this[a.groupId]);
  }
  this[a.groupId].occurrence = Math.max(this[a.groupId].occurrence, a.occurrence);
}, Object.create(null));



//Final logic to sum of previous occurence for each element group and start current elements item number with +1
var myItemNumber = 0;
var groupId = 0;
var finalArrayResult = [];

for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
  const element = data[index];
  var indexOfStevie = result.findIndex(i => i.groupId === element.groupId);
  var occurenceSum = 0;
  result.forEach((elem, idx) => {
    if (idx < indexOfStevie) {
      occurenceSum = occurenceSum + elem.occurrence
    }
  });
  console.log(occurenceSum);
  if (groupId !== element.groupId) {
    groupId = element.groupId;
    myItemNumber = 0;
  }
  element.itemNumber = occurenceSum + myItemNumber + 1;
  myItemNumber++;
  finalArrayResult.push(element);
}

console.log(finalArrayResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array first using the key date and then sort the array using the key "groupId"(relative to "date") i.e. items with the same date will consider as an individual lists.

Once sorting is done you can just iterate the array and start assigning values from 1.

Comment: Hey can you give me the working solution, I am not able solve this problem